# Object initialization syntax

Tags: syntax, f#, object-initializers

I'm just starting out with F# and I can't find the syntax to do object initialization like in C# 3.

I.e. given this:

```
public class Person {
  public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

how do I write the following in F#:

```
var p = new Person { Name = "John", BirthDate = DateTime.Now };
```

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
let p = new Person (Name = "John", BirthDate = DateTime.Now)
```

Comment: By convention **new** is only used with disposable classes.

Answer (score 100):

the answer from CMS is definitely correct. Here is just one addition that may be also helpful. In F#, you often want to write the type just using immutable properties. When using the "object initializer" syntax, the properties have to be mutable. An alternative in F# is to use named arguments, which gives you a similar syntax, but keeps things immutable:

```
type Person(name:string, ?birthDate) =
  member x.Name = name
  member x.BirthDate = defaultArg birthDate System.DateTime.MinValue
```

Now we can write:

```
let p1 = new Person(name="John", birthDate=DateTime.Now)
let p2 = new Person(name="John")
```

The code requires you to specify the name, but birthday is an optional argument with some default value.

Comment: Thanks Tomas, but in my case Person is in another assembly and I can't change it :(

Answer (score 6):

You can also omit the `new` keyword and use less verbose syntax:

```
let p = Person(BirthDate = DateTime.Now, Name = "John")
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/constructors

Comment: new-less syntax looks quite better in F#