# How do I create a class instance and fill properties in F#?

Tags: syntax, f#, c#-to-f#

In C#, I can:

```
var n = new Person()
{
     FirstName = "John",
     LastName = "Smith"
};
```

Can I do the same in F#? I mean, to create a class *and* specify some properties.

Comment: possible duplicate of [F# object initialization syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371878/f-object-initialization-syntax)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes:

```
let n = Person(FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith")
```

Note that the F# approach is actually much more flexible than the C# approach, in that you can use "post hoc" property assignments with *any* method call (not just constructors).  For example, if the `Person` type has a static method called `CreatePerson : string -> Person` which creates a new person and assigns the first name, you could also use it like:

```
let n = Person.CreatePerson("John", LastName = "Smith")
```

Comment: Is method call + property assignment covered in the MSDN docs?

Comment: @Daniel - a brief search didn't turn anything up.  It is buried in the spec in the method application resolution section, though: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597639.

Comment: I've read this before, but never used it, so I completely forgot about it. Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 4):

F# also has [records](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx) which are basically classes with automatically exposed properties that are meant to represent simple aggregates of named values, optionally with members.

```
type Person = {
    FirstName : string;
    LastName : string;
}

let p = {FirstName = "John"; LastName = "Smith"}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
type Person() =

    [<DefaultValue>]
    val mutable firstName : string

    [<DefaultValue>]
    val mutable lastName : string

    member x.FirstName 
        with get() = x.firstName 
        and set(v) = x.firstName <- v

    member x.LastName 
        with get() = x.lastName 
        and set(v) = x.lastName <- v

let p = new Person(FirstName = "Nyi", LastName = "Than")
```