# In F#, what is the object initializer syntax with a mandatory constructor parameter?

Tags: c#, f#, c#-to-f#

Let's say there's a class that with one public constructor, which takes one parameter. In addition, there are also multiple public properties I'd like to set. What would be the syntax for that in F#? For instance in C#

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }

    public SomeClass(string s)
    { }
}

//And associated usage.
var sc = new SomeClass("") { SomeProperty = "" };
```

In F# I can get this done using either the constructor or [property setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371878/object-initialization-syntax), but not both at the same time as in C#. For example, the following aren't valid

```
let sc1 = new SomeClass("", SomeProperty = "")
let sc2 = new SomeClass(s = "", SomeProperty = "")
let sc3 = new SomeClass("")(SomeProperty = "")
```

It looks like I'm missing something, but what?

**<edit:** As pointed out by **David**, doing it all in F# works, but for some reason, at least for me :), it gets difficult when the class to be used in F# is defined in C#. As for an example on such is [TopicDescription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.topicdescription.aspx) (to make up something public enough as for an added example). One can write, for instance

```
let t = new TopicDescription("", IsReadOnly = true)
```

and the corresponding compiler error will be `Method 'set_IsReadOnly' is not accessible from this code location`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you're having is that [`IsReadOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.entitydescription.isreadonly.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=fsharp#code-snippet-1) has an internal setter.

```
member IsReadOnly : bool with get, internal set
```

If you want to set it directly you're going to need to subclass `TopicDescription`.

The constructor syntax you're looking at is perfectly acceptable.

```
let test = new Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.TopicDescription("", EnableBatchedOperations=true)
```

compiles just fine for me.

Comment: You are right. What has led me astry is that my VS didn't add squiggles when I tried in C# ``var td = new TopicDescription("") { IsReadOnly = true };``. So, I just assumed that in this case ``TopicDescription`` and a bunch of other C# class initializations would compile. How silly I've been!

Answer (score 6):

I never program in F#, but this seems to work fine for me:

```
type SomeClass(s : string) =
    let mutable _someProperty = ""
    let mutable _otherProperty = s
    member this.SomeProperty with get() = _someProperty and set(value) = _someProperty <- value
    member this.OtherProperty with get() = _otherProperty and set(value) = _otherProperty <- value

let s = new SomeClass("asdf", SomeProperty = "test");

printf "%s and %s" s.OtherProperty s.SomeProperty;
```

That outputs `"asdf and test"`.

---

Additionally, the following code works fine for me:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }

    public SomeClass(string s)
    {
        this.OtherProperty = s;
    }
}
```

Then in F#:

```
let s = SomeClass("asdf", SomeProperty = "test")
```

Comment: It does, but in this case ``SomeClass`` is a C# class I need to use (e.g. [TopicDescription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.topicdescription.aspx)) is such one. Thanks for putting this here, though, I see I need to clarify my question.